# Is it true that $f$ continuous positive integrable on $[0,+\infty)$ implies $f(x)=o(1/x)$, $x\to+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I proved that if $f$ is continuous positive decreasing integrable function on $[0,+\infty)$ then $f=o(1/x)$ for $x\to+\infty$. Now I'm wondering is this also true if I suppose that $f$ isn't decreasing: i.e. is it true that $f(x)=o(1/x)$ for $x\to+\infty$ if $f$ is continue positive integrable on $[0,+\infty)$? I suspect that the answer is No so is there a simple counter-example?

Comment: No, and there is the classic spike counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every integer $n\ge 1$, draw a triangle (or "spike") of height $1$ and width $2^{-n}$, centred at $n$. The area of each triangle is $2^{-(n+1)}$, so the function $f$ thus depicted is integrable, with $\int_0^\infty f=\frac12$. But $\lim\sup f = 1$.

Comment: Yes I see it! Thanks.

Comment: It’s interesting to me that you see the MSE logo as spiralling clockwise; I always saw it spiralling counterclockwise!